# How can i insert data in temp_table using stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I have created this stored procedure and when i am calling it, it should return 3 column i.e day,month, year for august month in which in day column 1-30 days should be feeded and in month column 8 should come 30 times and similarly in year 2016 should come, but it is running endlessly while calling

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `Employee`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_insert_date_data`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_insert_date_data`
(start_date DATE, end_date DATE)
BEGIN

    SET @date_count=0;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_date
    (
        day_n INT(2),month_n INT(2), year_n INT(4)
    );
    WHILE(start_date <= end_date)
    DO
        INSERT INTO tmp_date(day_n,month_n,year_n)
        VALUES
        (EXTRACT(DAY FROM start_date),EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date),EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date));

    END WHILE;
SELECT * FROM tmp_date;

END$$


call sp_insert_date_data('2016-08-01','2016-08-30')
```

Comment: Please help me as soon as you can

Comment: add a `commit` after each `insert` or at least after the `end while` statement , which may help you.

Comment: The while loop has no exit ability, try incrementing the start_date by 1 day after the insert. Also date_count seems to have no purpose.

Comment: Thanks Avishek and P.Salmon